# Secondary monitor can't be set as primary in XP

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

This is for my work computer, so I am stuck with XP.

I'm using a laptop and a secondary monitor.

I can extend the desktop to my secondary monitor without a problem.

When I check off "Use this device as the primary monitor" checkbox and hit "Apply", the secondary monitor is disabled entirely (no longer extended) and only my laptop works.  I have no idea why this is occurring, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the graphics card settings tool as opposed to the windows XP settings and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an updated display driver... Display drivers are sometimes just old and incapable.

You may be able to go into display properties where you see the two displays named 1 and 2 and grab one and drag it to the other side of two.  If you need to switch them.